# Install npm module from git that does not have package.json at root

Tags: javascript, npm, nativescript, npm-install, package.json

I want to install the `master` branch of https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular into my JS project.

npm supports this via:
`npm i NativeScript/nativescript-angular@master`

However, the actual module (and its [package.json](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/tree/master/nativescript-angular/package.json)) is in a `nativescript-angular` subdirectory.  Because of this, the command above fails.

How do I pull this off?  Or is it really [not supported](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974)?

Comment: May I know why you are trying to install from master? It's recommend to use the `@next` version if you are looking for a fix that is not yet available in GA release. If you are still interested to install from master, you have to compile the JS version of the plugin like any other NativeScript plugin and point the compiled files in your package.json.

Comment: github release 7.1.1 (same as `master` at time of writing) contains a regression bug fix for https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/pull/1667.  7.1.0 is latest published on npmjs.com (7 days after release).  @next just installs `7.1.0-next`.  I have a comment in the 7.1.1 release here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/pull/1668

Comment: In that case you may even directly point the release tar file in your `package.json`.

Comment: You sure? You have an `npm install` example using tar for nativescript-angular? tar method for this repo has the same problem (package.json not in root)

Comment: Yes, we can install from a Github release tar if that was compiled but unfortunately here the release tar contains the same uncompiled source files. So the only option left is to clone the repo, run a build manually and point the compiled files in package.json.

Comment: thats unfortunate